# see if cookie exists on the same file as they were set

Tags: php, cookies

In a file I have this code to set some cookies

```
setcookie("token", "value", time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
setcookie("secret", "value", time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
setcookie("key", "value", time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
```

I want to know how I can check if these cookies were set on the same file, preferably just after they're set. I have tried this

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['token']) || !isset($_COOKIE['secret']) || !isset($_COOKIE['key']){

//do something

}
```

but it doesn't work..

Comment: Cookies are only set when they are sent back to the browser, and can only be tested by PHP when the browser issues a new request... so "No! they don't exist in the script in which they were set"

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9415282/php-cookie-isset

Comment: Superglobals are set when the script is started up, then PHP does NOT change them to reflect anything you've done within the script.

Answer (score 0):

the $_COOKIE  is set when the user already have a cookie and ask for a new page.

You can't setcookie  then use $_COOKIE right after

Comment: Is there any way I could see if the cookie was set then?

Answer (score 0):

We shouldn't really bother with your question as you didn't take any advice from your previous question about the exact same problem, but here goes:

**Option A**

```
// As you do setCookie, also set the value in $_COOKIE
setCookie("foobar", "bat", time() + COOKIE_LIFETIME);
$_COOKIE["foobar"] = "bat";

var_dump($_COOKIE["foobar"]);
```

**Option B**

Don't use `$_COOKIE` to store your information. Have separated variables `$token`, `$secret` and `$key` and load these with the values from `$_COOKIE`. If `$_COOKIE` is empty, initialize them manually and call `setCookie`.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["token"]))
    $token = $_COOKIE["token"];
else
{
    $token = "defaultValue";
    setCookie("token", $token, COOKIE_LIFETIME);
}
// Use $token instead of $_COOKIE["token"] from now on.
```

**Option C**

If the user does not have the cookies set, do `setCookie` and relocate the user to the same site again with `header()`. Beware of infinite relocates if the user does not allow you to set cookies.

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE["token"])
{
    setCookie("token", "defaultValue", COOKIE_LIFETIME);
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); // insert reasonable URL here.
    exit;
}
```

Option B would be the preferred one. Hope to not see this question asked a third time.

You can't check in the same request if the user will send your cookies in future requests. `setCookie` is merely an appeal to the users browser to please attach this information to future requests. You will know if it works, if the cookie is send on the next request. If it does not following 3 scenarios are possible: a) The user's browser does not allow you to set cookies, b) the user has not visited your website before, c) previously set cookies have expired.